# systemd service not being triggered by its timer unit

Tags: systemd, systemctl, systemd-timer

Here is my service unit definition

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc /usr/local/bin//myservice
# ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID
EnvironmentFile=/etc/myservice/config
User=myuser
Group=mygroup
```

and its timer unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for myservice

[Timer]
Unit=myservice.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* 10:33:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

I have tentatively set the `OnCalendar` to `*-*-* 10:33:00` (followed by a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`) but as a I was watching my machine, I didn't see the service firing. I had also set it for 5AM but this morning I saw no evidence of execution

When I perform a manual `sudo systemctl start myservice` it works as expected.

What might be preventing the service from executing according to its `timer` schedule?

Comment: So what does `systemctl list-timers` output? It tells when it will execute.

Comment: You are right, it is not listed there! Any idea how can I dig deeper into why?

Comment: You did not start the timer. `sudo systemctl start myservice.timer`

Comment: wish I could throw a facepalm emoji here. thanks; post it as an answer so that I can accept it you'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not start the timer.

```
sudo systemctl start myservice.timer
```